# Run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14)': Automation error

Tags: sql, excel, vba

1.) Error happens during the line "Set rs = conn.Execute(SQLCODE)", But when i run the SQL code in SQL management studio it runs without any error. Can you guys help on this?

```vb
Sub ConnectSqlServer()

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sConnString As String
Dim SQLCODE As String
' Create the connection string.
sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=MSPRTDBP;" & _
              "Initial Catalog=MSPWIP;" & _
               "Integrated Security=SSPI;"

' Create the Connection and Recordset objects.
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

 conn.Open sConnString
SQLCODE = "Select WoIDfromTable1"

Set rs = conn.Execute(SQLCODE)
' Check we have data.
If Not rs.EOF Then
    ' Transfer result.
    Worksheets("Base").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("A2:H500").Clear
    ActiveSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
' Close the recordset
    rs.Close
Else
    MsgBox "Error: No records returned.", vbCritical
End If
' Clean up
If CBool(conn.State And adStateOpen) Then conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the spaces at the end of each lines for `SQLCODE`

Replace it with this instead

```
SQLCODE = "SELECT WOID, PN, WOQTY, StartDate, CS, Station, SUM(QtyStarted) AS QtyStart, SUM(FailedQty) AS QtyFail FROM(SELECT r.WorkOrderBatch AS WOID, wo.ProductCode AS PN, wo.WorkOrderQty AS WOQTY, CONVERT(DATE, wo.StartDate) AS StartDate, wo.CurrentStatus AS CS,  " & _
          "CASE PCID WHEN 'AC.01.BN.01' THEN 'Burn-in' WHEN 'AC.01.FT.01' THEN 'Final' WHEN 'AC.01.FT.02' THEN 'Final' WHEN 'AC.01.FT.02' THEN 'Final' ELSE NULL END AS Station, COUNT(DISTINCT r.UnitIdentifier) AS QtyStarted, SUM(CASE r.IsTestPass WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS FailedQty FROM [MSPTestResult].[MSPTestResult].[Result] r " & _
          "JOIN [MSPWIP].[MSPWIP].[WorkOrder](NOLOCK)wo ON r.workorderbatch=wo.workordernumber JOIN [MSPWIP].[MSPWIP].[BillOfOperation](NOLOCK)bo ON wo.wipworkorderid=bo.wipworkorderid AND bo.operationdescription=r.teststage " & _
          "WHERE 1=1 AND PCID IN ('AC.01.BN.01', 'AC.01.FT.01', 'AC.01.FT.02', 'AC.01.FT.02')AND wo.ProductCode IN ('R350-102')AND(wo.StartDate>(GETDATE()-7)OR wo.CurrentStatus IN ('In Progress')) " & _
          "GROUP BY r.WorkOrderBatch, wo.ProductCode, WorkOrderQty, StartDate, CurrentStatus, (PCID)) AS SUB GROUP BY WOID, PN, WOQTY, StartDate, CS, Station ORDER BY WOID ASC;"
```

Comment: There's also a space missing before each `When` and the `Else`.  Can you do `COUNT(DISTINCT r.UnitIdentifier)` - not sure which flavour of SQL it should be, so do `CASE` statements work as well?  Missing space before `AND` in `('R350-102')AND`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Good spot - Just reformatted the whole SQL query in SSMS. Think that should've got all of them now